# Select only tables where a column contains a certain numeric value

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, plpgsql

Is it possible to select only tables where a column (`AD_CLIENT_ID`) contains a certain numeric value (`1000000`)?

I have 850 tables to select from and each table has this column, but not all columns contain 1000000.

Comment: I don't think it's effective.(I mean , 850 tables?)
You should think and re-organize your database structre and logic.

Comment: Please explain why you (think that you) need 850 tables.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is customary here to cut to the chase of the question. No personal introduction, no formalities, no signature - your name and avatar show up under your posts anyway. But details of your problem are important. Like why you have 850 tables in your database. The database-design might be improved.

Answer (score 2):

hmm..

- strongly reconsider your design.
- Make a view of a huge UNION structure
  of all your tables, then query that WHERE AD_CLIENT_ID  = 100000

Comment: Hi Randy, using the following statement I was able to retreive all tables that have column AD_CLIENT_ID. How would add condition where AD_CLIENT_ID = 100000?   SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE COLUMN_NAME IN ('columnA','ColumnB')
        AND TABLE_SCHEMA='YourDatabase';

Comment: you can't do both at the same time.  Your query can be used as the cursor which in turn can be used to write a sql statement for all the tables...  you can either run that dynamically, or save it to a script to create a view.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the list of tables with a plpgsql function executing dynamic SQL, looping through the results from the catalog. Consider the following demo, tested on PostgreSQL 9.1, but should work at least with version 8.4 or even older:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tbl_with_value(numeric)
  RETURNS SETOF text AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    _tbl text;
BEGIN

FOR _tbl IN
    SELECT DISTINCT quote_ident(n.nspname) || '.' || quote_ident(c.relname)
    FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
    JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_class c ON c.oid = a.attrelid
    JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
    WHERE  a.attname = 'ad_client_id'
    AND    a.attisdropped = FALSE -- column hasn't been dropped
    AND    n.nspname = 'myschema' -- search only this schema
    AND    c.relkind = 'r'  -- only real tables
LOOP    
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE '
    SELECT ''' || _tbl || '''::text
    WHERE  EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM   ' || _tbl || '
        WHERE  ad_client_id = $1
        )'
    USING $1;
END LOOP;

END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Call:

```
SELECT * FROM x.f_tbl_with_value(100000)
```

#### Major points

- Result is a list of table names where the column `ad_client_id` exists and contains the parameter value in at least one row.
- I use the PostgreSQL catalog. You can do the same with the SQL standard information schema like you demonstrate in your comment. But that's a lot slower and is only useful if you want to keep your code portable. As this plpgsql function is not portable to other database systems anyway, I use the faster PostgreSQL catalog tables.
- Note how I use plain SQL to retrieve the table names, but [dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) to query them.
- Note how I use [`quote_ident()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) on schema and table name to safeguard against SQL injection and automatically preserve mixed case identifiers if need should be.
- I used the lower case string `'ad_client_id'` for the column name. Or do you actually need upper case because you double-quoted `"AD_CLIENT_ID"` when creating it? (I generally advise to use lower case identifiers only. [More about that in the manual.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS))